# How to $filter attachments list endpoint by isInline?

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-restapi, outlook-web-app, outlook-graph-api

I'm developing OWA add-in using OWA REST API

I'm not able to get the filtered result when fetch the attachment list with `$filter=inlinImage eq true` for example:

`https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/{id}/attachments?$filter=IsInline%20eq%20true`

or

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{id}/attachments?$filter=IsInline%20eq%20true`

knowing that is says [in the resource reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#Attachment) that isInline is Filterable, and I got the response 200 when doing the requests above but the without filtering the data by that query params

Is this an expected behaviour? how can I get this data otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

this may be of help to someone looking for help filtering attachments from ms graph endpoint.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues

$filter:
/attachments endpoint does not support filters. If present, the $filter parameter is ignored.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30700825)