# How to try the preview requirement set in OfficeJs

Tags: office-js

I'm developing an Outlook Web App add-in.

I'm trying to test [getSharedPropertiesAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/preview-requirement-set/office.context.mailbox.item#getsharedpropertiesasyncoptions-callback) but I'm getting

`Office.context.mailbox.item.getSharedPropertiesAsync is not a function`

I tested it from both read and compose mode, as it should be supported in both,

in the manifest I set the version to `1.7` in

```
<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
   <Requirements>
     <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.7"> // <- HERE
       <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
     </bt:Sets>
   </Requirements>
```

and

```
<Requirements>
  <Sets>
    <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.7" />
  </Sets>
</Requirements>
```

Knowing that I added the `SupportsSharedFolders` in the manifest:

```
<DesktopFormFactor>
 <SupportsSharedFolders>true</SupportsSharedFolders>
 <!-- Location of the Functions that UI-less buttons can trigger (ExecuteFunction Actions). -->
 <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />
```

And I'm testing OWA on the new experience and I joined `Insider Fast` in Outlook mac, but I did not find a way to join OWA.

Also, some of the other functions works fine, like [getAttachmentsAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/preview-requirement-set/office.context.mailbox.item#getattachmentsasyncoptions-callback--arrayattachmentdetails) which is also in preview! And last thing, it shows that `shared properties` is on prod in [this video](https://youtu.be/M4OIFsxXLl0?t=358), so that's so confusing!!!!!!!

Should preview requirements set work on the latest version `V1.7`? if not, is there a way to get the preview requirements set on the manifest?

I HOPE I CAN GET RESPONSE FROM MSF TEAM AS THEY ARE REALLLY BAD WITH RESPONSE LIKE [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57075314/how-to-fetch-a-specific-inline-image-using-owa-rest-api), [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56934389/how-to-get-attachments-content-35mb-by-owa-rest-api?noredirect=1&lq=1) AND [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57072540/how-to-filter-attachments-list-endpoint-by-isinline)!!!

Comment: Yeah it's easy to give -1, but it's soo hard to answer!

Comment: For your other questions, with the preview APIs (getAttachmentsAsync, getAttachmentContentAsync) you can get the attachment contents. _Note: Preview APIs can change and may not be supported by all client._

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to check whether preview requirement is supported or not.
May be you can try your luck by checking for `V1.8`.

Answer to your actual question:

As the documentation suggests [getSharedPropertiesAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/preview-requirement-set/office.context.mailbox.item#getsharedpropertiesasyncoptions-callback) is supported on items in a shared folder.

> Gets the properties of the selected appointment or message in a **shared** folder, calendar, or mailbox.

Make sure you are trying the API on an item from shared folder. Calling the API on normal item throws below error.

`Office.context.mailbox.item.getSharedPropertiesAsync is not a function`

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, I got confused, it said: in a shared folder, calendar, or mailbox. so how about mailbox?

Comment: to explain more of what I did: I create shared mailbox, login to it from another account, changed the manifest, and install it, and tried to do `getSharedPropertiesAsync`

Comment: I am not sure, what you are trying here. If I understand properly the API provides you with the permissions of a item/folder/mailbox, which is [delegated](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/manage-another-person-s-mail-and-calendar-items-afb79d6b-2967-43b9-a944-a6b953190af5) by another person.